# Foreign key constraint to cross check user rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

How can I use the foreign key to force insert/update query to be successful only if the foreign key data is actually belong to the user who is doing the insert/update.

For example, a category created by user 1 cannot be used by user 2 and vice-versa to disallow cross-access.

```
Create Table Users(
    user_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(50) not null,
    city varchar(50) default null,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

-- Insert users
Insert into Users(user_name, city) Values('Nick', 'New york');
Insert into Users(user_name, city) Values('John', 'Seattle');
```

Create categories

```
Create Table Categories(
    category_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int not null,
    category_name varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CategoryUser FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)  
);

-- Insert category for Nick with user_id = 1
Insert into Categories(user_id, category_name) Values(1, 'Travel');

-- Insert category for John user_id = 2
Insert into Categories(user_id, category_name) Values(2, 'Science');
```

Create books

```
Create Table Books(
    book_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int not null,
    category_id int default null,    
    book_name varchar(50) not null,
    book_type varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_BookUser FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_BookCategory FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Categories(category_id)
);
```

Now the insert book for Nick **MUST FAIL** because "Science" category with `category_id = 2` row belongs to John with `user_id = 1`

```
Insert into Books(user_id, category_id, book_name, book_type)
Values(1, 2, 'My science book', 'online')
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Books ADD UNIQUE KEY (category_id);` this makes it an error for more than one row in Books to have a given category_id. Therefore only one user may use each category.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's not correct. The user who own this category should be able to add more books for that category so can't make it unique. I just need to limit other users who doesn't own that category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `Categories.user_id`, you can make that a key:

```
ALTER TABLE Categories ADD UNIQUE KEY (user_id, category_id);
```

Then reference it from the Books table:

```
ALTER TABLE Books ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id, category_id) 
  REFERENCES Categories (user_id, category_id);
```

This requires that a book be given to a user only if that user is assigned the respective category. But it permits multiple rows in Books with the same user & category pair.

It seems redundant to make the new key in Categories a UNIQUE KEY, since the category_id alone is already unique. But in general SQL language, a foreign key must reference a UNIQUE KEY.